# Building circular svg path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working with a dataset that has all the points required to build a circle. I need to utilize the dataset to build a svg **`path`** (and **not** svg `circle`) element that is circular.

I tried as following which did not work.
What path commands can I use to make the path appear like a full circle.

```js
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const data = [{
    "x": 384,
    "y": 552
}, {
    "x": 440.4273842,
    "y": 533.6656315
}, {
    "x": 475.3014256,
    "y": 485.6656315
}, {
    "x": 475.3014256,
    "y": 426.3343685
}, {
    "x": 440.4273842,
    "y": 378.3343685
}, {
    "x": 384,
    "y": 360
}, {
    "x": 327.5726158,
    "y": 378.3343685
}, {
    "x": 292.6985744,
    "y": 426.3343685
}, {
    "x": 292.6985744,
    "y": 485.6656315
}, {
    "x": 327.5726158,
    "y": 533.6656315
}, {
    "x": 384,
    "y": 552
}];

const svg = d3.select('#viz')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 600, 600');

svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', () => {
        return d3.line().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y)(data)
    })
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>   
    <div id="viz"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may try to replace the L command with A96,96 1 0 0 where 96, 96 is the radius of the circle

Comment: Define "didn't work". A bunch of lines only looks like a circle if there's a **lot** of lines, otherwise it looks like a polygon (or a decagon in this case). You can use `curve` but closing it off requires attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

d3 is not really helpfull when it comes to writing the SVG arc command. Both [path.arc](https://github.com/d3/d3-path/blob/v3.1.0/README.md#path_arc) and [path.arcTo](https://github.com/d3/d3-path/blob/v3.1.0/README.md#path_arcTo) use parameters that demand recomputing your data, only so that internally the computation can be reversed. It is easier just to write the attribute string directly.

This requires the knowledge of three values in advance:

- the `radius` of your circle,
- the `largeArc` flag: 0 for arcs less than half a circle, 1 for arcs that are longer
- the `sweep` flag: 0 for counterclockwise arcs, 1 for clockwise arcs.

```js
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const data = [{
    "x": 384,
    "y": 552
}, {
    "x": 440.4273842,
    "y": 533.6656315
}, {
    "x": 475.3014256,
    "y": 485.6656315
}, {
    "x": 475.3014256,
    "y": 426.3343685
}, {
    "x": 440.4273842,
    "y": 378.3343685
}, {
    "x": 384,
    "y": 360
}, {
    "x": 327.5726158,
    "y": 378.3343685
}, {
    "x": 292.6985744,
    "y": 426.3343685
}, {
    "x": 292.6985744,
    "y": 485.6656315
}, {
    "x": 327.5726158,
    "y": 533.6656315
}, {
    "x": 384,
    "y": 552
}];

const r = 96;
const largeArc = 0;
const sweep = 0;

const svg = d3.select('#viz')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 600, 600');

svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', () => {
        return data.reduce((path, d, i) => {
            if (i) {
                path += `A${r} ${r} 0 ${largeArc}${sweep}${d.x},${d.y}`;
            } else {
                path += `M${d.x},${d.y}`;
            }
            return path;
        }, "");
    })
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>   
    <div id="viz"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering your specific question - you want to change those "L" commands which are straight line commands, to "A" commands which are arc draw commands. The format of "A" commands is:   A|a]rx,ry, x-axis-rotation, large-arc-flag, sweep-flag, x,y

That gives you the following in your case:

```html
<svg width="600px" height="400px" viewBox="0 200 1200 800">
  
    <path d="M384,552
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 440.427,533.666 
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 475.301,485.666 
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 475.301,426.334 
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 440.427,378.334 
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 384,360
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 327.573,378.334
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 292.699,426.334 
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 292.699,485.666
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 327.573,533.666
        A 100,100,0, 0, 0, 384,552  "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Micheal, sorry for cutting in. @smpa01 I saw this answer only just before publishing my own. Please consider it to just answer your question "How can I programmatically generate this part". As for the value of the radius, without further knowledge of how your data are redived at, that is impossible to answer.

Comment: No worries @ccprog. OP can find the center of the circle from three points on it. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/get-the-equation-of-a-circle-when-given-3-points. Then the distance between any point and the center will give you the radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the D3 curve method to create a smooth transition between points.

```js
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const data=[{x:384,y:552},{x:440.4273842,y:533.6656315},{x:475.3014256,y:485.6656315},{x:475.3014256,y:426.3343685},{x:440.4273842,y:378.3343685},{x:384,y:360},{x:327.5726158,y:378.3343685},{x:292.6985744,y:426.3343685},{x:292.6985744,y:485.6656315},{x:327.5726158,y:533.6656315},{x:384,y:552}];

const svg = d3.select('#viz')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 600, 600');
    
const curve = d3.line().curve(d3.curveNatural);
const points = data.map(Object.values); // [[384, 552], [440.4273842, 533.6656315] ...]

svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', curve(points))
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>   
    <div id="viz"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The shape does not look like a perfect circle.